# jStorage support for sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, sessionstorage, jstorage

I am using [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) to store data locally with JavaScript.

Have not been able to determine how to specify sessionStorage in place of the default localStorage.

Anyone know if it is possible to use sessionStorage with jStorage, and if so, the syntax?

The default localStorage [example](http://www.jstorage.info/#example) works fine.